# Getting full hex integer

Tags: javascript, colors, hex

I am using parseInt to convert hex code to 16 bytes, colour number

```js
parseInt('ef7f31', 16) // 15695665
```

The above outputs `15695665` which is expected.
The problem comes when the hex has parts of RGB that are all zero then it shortens it. for example this colour #0098d9.

```js
parseInt('0098d9', 16) // 39129
```

The hex in the example above has red as all zeros, which makes the output `39129`. If I convert that output back to hex like this `(39129).toString(16)` it returns `98d9` with no zeros that were there in the first place. I could add the zeros but may not know which position

So my question is, how would I make it show the full number after converting the hex to int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is using `String.prototype.padStart()`

```
(39129).toString(16).padStart(6,"0")
//"0098d9"
```

Since only zeros at MSB end will be ignored, padding leading zeros when converting back to hexadecimal strings is enough to recover the RGB representation.

Or you may want to take more systematic approaches like storing `R`, `G`, `B` values separately and concatenate them when converting back to hexadecimal strings.

Comment: This quite answers my question, but is it possible make the int value itself (39129) to be the full length counting the zeroes so I don't have to add the zeroes after converting back to hex? For example if I was to send this to an API and they convert the int back to hex but don't add the pad for me

Comment: @EcksDee I don't think it is possible since the size of a type is fixed for a specific language. In the case of `Number` in Javascript, it is a 64-bit floating point IEEE 754 number. For the condition you mentioned, if that API is designed for colors, it should implement a proper scheme to interpret integers. If it is a general purpose API, then it is your duty to handle the parsing of the data.